# How to use moveTaskToBack() ??

Tags: android

moveTaskToBack() function is not found, I have tried using **ActivityManager.moveTaskToBack()** and **Activity.moveTaskToBack()** but there is no function of such type.
How can I use it ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is

```
moveTaskToBack(boolean)
```

so if you want to move it to back, you must call

```
moveTaskToBack(true);
```

btw: if you are using eclipse just move your mouse pointer on function and some yellow window will show with all explanation of it